# NullPointerException: .... virtual method 'android.bluetooth.le.ScanRecord android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult.getScanRecord()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm using the function getScanRecord in this line of code:

```java
if (!(this.mScanResult.getScanRecord().getServiceData() == null || this.mScanResult.getScanRecord().getServiceData().size() == 0)) {
    advertisementData = advertisementData + "Service Data: " + this.mScanResult.getScanRecord().getServiceData().toString().replace('{', ' ').replace('}', ' ') + "\n";
}
```

And it gives me this error in Android Studio:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.catu.catucomm/com.catu.catucomm.Second}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.bluetooth.le.ScanRecord android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult.getScanRecord()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, I suspect that your **'mScanResult'** variable is *empty*. Check whether your **'mScanResult'** is *empty or not* at that moment of code.

Try this.

```
    /*Listener sur le btn Pair*/
    mPairBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_SCAN_RESULT, -YOU NEED TO PUT YOUR SCAN RESULT HERE- );
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
        }
    });
```

You need to pass your scan result object to the second activity with this putExtra() function.

Comment: Thank you, actually, I declared my variable 'mScanResult' like this : private ScanResult mScanResult ; Then i use it here in OnCreate() function like this :              this.mScanResult = (ScanResult) intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRAS_SCAN_RESULT);
/****THEN*******/ : if (this.mScanResult.getScanRecord().getDeviceName() != null && !this.mScanResult.getScanRecord().getDeviceName().isEmpty()) {
                advertisementData = advertisementData + "Device Name: " + this.mScanResult.getScanRecord().getDeviceName() + "\n";
            } .....

Comment: Is 'Second' class activity? If it is, you can't declare your own constructor for an activity like that. You need to use intent for passing data as you did at first.

Comment: I used this to solve the first problem : private ScanResult mScanResult;
public Second(ScanResult mScanResult) 
{
       this.mScanResult = mScanResult;
} How to use intent, my class is named Second, and now i have the new problem ; java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.catu.catucomm.Second> has no zero argument constructor

Comment: First, if your 'Second' class is an activity, you can't declare your own constructor like this

`
private ScanResult mScanResult;
public Second(ScanResult mScanResult) 
{
       this.mScanResult = mScanResult;
}
`

So you need to get rid of that, and you need to use intent. 

About using an intent, actually, you already used it. 

`
this.mScanResult = (ScanResult) intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRAS_SCAN_RESULT);
`

So go back to this method, and we have to find another problem caused in another place.

Comment: Can you check your 'EXTRAS_SCAN_RESULT' variable has the same value as the one in a previous activity?

Comment: It is always declared like this : public static final String EXTRAS_SCAN_RESULT = "SCAN_RESULT"; yes it has the same value

Comment: Can you give me a full code of the Second activity and previous activity? It is so hard to know what is the problem with this information

Comment: Yes this is my Second Activity code : https://www.codepile.net/pile/dyVWoAPQ And this is the previous Activity : https://www.codepile.net/pile/xkwEmrBz

Comment: I updated my answer. If you have more questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I Have soved the problem by initializing the variable like this :

```
private ScanResult mScanResult;
public Second(ScanResult mScanResult) 
{
       this.mScanResult = mScanResult;
}
```

but now i have the new problem :

**java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.catu.catucomm.Second> has no zero argument constructor**

Comment: Please don't post new problems in your answer, but open a new question if you're still stuck.